# setParameter at form

Tags: java, http-unit

I want submit form with some parameters using httpunit.
I wrote smt like

```
WebForm form = response.getFormWithID(formId);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(form1.getParameterNames())); //it contains "a"
form.setParameter( "a", "bla-bla"); //exception
form.submit();
```

But it throws runtime exception `org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: "Form" is not a constructor.` Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Why use HttpUnit, it's pretty old. HtmlUnit is much, much nicer, does a very similar task, and is actively maintained.

Comment: @skaffman, Hm.. I should think about migrating. Thanks. I'll read about HtmlUnit.

Comment: @skaffman, post you comments as answer, please. HtmlUnit useful think and I want accept your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpUnit is old and no longer maintained, and also not very widely used.

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is its spiritual successor. It does the same job, but it has a better API, it works better, and it's actively maintained.